# HighCharts. How to set a fixed width for a chart grid, not including labels?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to set a fixed width for a chart grid, not including labels? The fixed width should be between the columns, at the columns and along the edges. Labels area must be dynamic.

Width between the columns - 24px.
Column width - 28px.
Width between edge and column - 12px.

**Grid width - 104px.**

https://snag.gy/8twGXT.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/2481ht7L/15/

I tried to set the width of the "g" tag through css, did not work.

```html
<g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid"></g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `load` event you can update the chart with calculated `marginRight` property and adjust `pointPadding` to the required dimensions:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    type: 'column',
    marginRight: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            if (this.chartWidth < 104) {
                this.setSize(104);
            } else {
                this.update({
                    chart: {
                        marginRight: this.chartWidth - 104
                    }
                }, true, false, false);
            }
        }
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        grouping: false,
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPadding: 0.23
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kzdLyp1g/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginRight

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSize

Comment: How to redraw the chart when resizing the window?

Comment: Hi @Nazar Ugrinovsky, You can change the `load` event to `render` and set a flag to prevent an infinity loop: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v2ma86bh/

Answer (score 0):

You can change `pointPadding` or `groupPadding` in configuration of chart.

Provide fiddle if above doesn't help.